# apache error: mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for

Tags: php, apache2, fastcgi

I have server with Debian 6,Apache 2.2.16,php 5.3.7. Whereon runs two page first.net - many visit user, second.net - much less page visit. When restart apache2,that run both page ok, but after few minutes/hours cant load page second.net. In /log/apache2/second.net/error is:

```
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/webuser/php5-wrap
```

In log /log/apache2/first.net is it certainly but less(given the number of user). When is error? What is wrong?

cat /var/www/webuser/php5-wrap

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=1
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi[/CODE]
```

cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
FcgidConnectTimeout 45
IPCConnectTimeout 100
MaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
MaxProcessCount 2
DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that you are simply running out of processes to deal with requests. You probably want to increase your MaxClients and/or MaxSpareServers.

See these articles for more info:

[Apache MaxSpareServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html#maxspareservers)

[Apache MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seemed to have helped in my case. I have many websites running on a single server, I also used the command "ps -aux" to look out for the specific website that was presenting the same error (can't apply process slot for [...]). Before that I used "top" command where I had a bunch of "php-cgi" processes.